# Make a split view with jQuery mobile and a single menu code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile, handheld

I am looking for a split view menu.
Identical as the settings menu in an ipad.

My application use jQuery and jQuery mobile.
I have found a plugin : http://asyraf9.github.com/jquery-mobile/

The matter is, with this plugin you need to copy the menu as much as you have pages.
I won't need to navigate like if it was a tree menu.

I have like 6 steps inside the menu and they always be the same.

The plugin is a bit bugged, so I was wondering how could I make my own static splitview menu using jquery mobile.